# Setting CSS 3 Transition and Transform in Javascript works in Chrome But not in IE 10, FF properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have the following  code,

```
    gallery.css("transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    gallery.css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    gallery.css("-moz-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    gallery.css("-ms-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    gallery.css("-o-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    //inverse the number we set in the css
    var value = (distance < 0 ? "" : "-") + Math.abs(distance).toString();

    gallery.css("transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0,0)");
    gallery.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0,0)");
    gallery.css("-moz-transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0,0)");
    gallery.css("-ms-transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0,0)");
    gallery.css("-o-transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0,0)");
```

which works greate in chrome, andriod, Iphone. But on IE 10(on Mobile) does not work and Firefox works partially. Any way to solve this in Javascript/Jquery?

[See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BJmyr/5)

**Update:** I think I got the main issue. The main issue is that touch events(touchstart, touchend, touchmove) not work in IE 10 mobile. I have used [IE 10 Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is work great for me. Thanks everyone.

Comment: The question has already been asked here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143953/css3-alternative-for-translate3d

Comment: @Brewal that question is 1,5 years old... "Much has changed since you lived here my friend".

Comment: Explain what "does not work" and "works partially" mean in your case.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov, Partially means it is very jurky

Comment: @PavloMykhalov, here is the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/BJmyr/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing which you should definitely keep in mind is the *order* in which you use vendor-specific prefixes. There *is* a difference between saying:

```
gallery.css("transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-moz-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-ms-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-o-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
```

and...

```
gallery.css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-moz-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-ms-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("-o-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
gallery.css("transition-duration", duration + "ms");
```

As mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7080605/1454806)'s [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080674/1454806):

> Whichever is last out of `-webkit-border-radius` and `border-radius` will be the one that's used.
>
> `-webkit-border-radius` is the "experimental" property - the implementation may contain deviations from the specification. The implementation for `border-radius` will match what's in the specification.
>
> It's preferable to have the "W3C implementation" used when it's available, to ensure consistency between all the browsers that support it.

With that said - be aware that your current implementation is likely to override the "W3C implemented" version with the vendor-specific experimental property.

On to a more specific answer to your question:

[This table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) may give you a bit more insight into which versions of which browsers claim support for 3d transformation CSS, from version to version.

1. **Internet Explorer**

   According to [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx), IE 10 supports full CSS3 3D Transformations (note that [IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx) only supported [2-D transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705), and previous versions didn't even support that).
2. **Firefox**

   As of the fixing of [Bug 505115](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505115), Firefox claims support of CSS3 3D-Transforms. According to [this example page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-transform#Browser_compatibility), as well - Mozilla does support the transformations (and even demonstrates doing so if you load that page in Firefox).

   Unfortunately, more complicated tests in Firefox fail. See [this link](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-03.html) for an example of something that works elegantly in Chrome, but not in FF. Partial support, to be sure, but without the animation of the WebKit implementation.

   Note: I am using Firefox 20.0.1 in order to test.
3. **Opera**

   Opera provides [this article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/) to describe their support of transforms.

**End Result**:

Support is coming to the major browsers, but slowly. Future versions claim more full support, but each vendor seems to have a different definition of what "full" means. So - as usual in the web-world... coder-beware... test in multiple environments and see what *actually* works before trusting the browsers to function properly in accordance with specs.

Comment: Your suggestion doen't work for me, Try this on IE 10 http://fiddle.jshell.net/BJmyr/5/show/

Comment: It seems the plugin whcih I am using only works in WebKit Browsers, https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues Is there is way to make it work

Comment: Honestly - probably not, until the other browsers catch up in their implementation of the features.

Answer (score 2):

While `Translate3d` is still not supported in all browsers, it *should* work in FF. Atm it's the only browser which [supports it without prefix](http://caniuse.com/#search=3d%20trans).

IE10 does not support `transform-style` with `preserve-3d`, so this might be an issue for you. Nonetheless 3d transforms are possible here.

I suggest you change your `tranlate3d` to `translateX` since you only modify the `X` value anyway. This could already solve your issue. Also in general it is recommended to declare the standard-conform value last (the prefix free form) since this is the preferred notation and not have some proprietary stuff override this.

Comment: besides the fact that it looks somehow broken it works for me in IE10. (if working means you can swipe through the imagegallery).

Comment: I have tested in Lumia 920(IE 10). It is not swaping. How come this is possible?

Comment: But not in Latest Nokia Lumia 920(IE 10). Please help me

Comment: @user960567 Have you tried changing the `translate3d` to `translate` or `translateX` as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Thanks. But it does'nt work. I think the plugin which I am using does not touch for Mobile IE 10. From the plugin, `This jQuery plugin will only run on devices running Mobile Webkit based browsers (iOS 2.0+, android 2.2+)`  Can we make this to work in IE 10

Comment: @user960567 I'm truly sorry, but I can't help then. This is way too much code to work through without getting the error. Perhaps try another swipe plugin?

Answer (score 1):

For Internet Explorer specific details, take a look at the MSDN document about [Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) features related to transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Looking at [transform-style property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it appears only to support `transform-style: flat`

The [Transform Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj200285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section lists a [translate3d() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj200286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> This section contains reference documentation for the Cascading Style
>   Sheets (CSS) transform functions that are supported in Windows
>   Internet Explorer. Support for 2-D Transforms was added in Windows
>   Internet Explorer 9, while support for 3-D Transforms was added in
>   Internet Explorer 10.